# Aliases don't work in interactive zsh

Tags: zsh, alias, shopt

I have a curious problem where my aliases are listed when I type `alias`, but they are not executable.

Here, I try to alias `d` to `date`:

```
% which alias
alias: shell built-in command
% alias d=/usr/bin/date
```

But it doesn't run:

```
% d
zsh: command not found: d
% /usr/bin/date
Sun 19 Apr 2020 20:30:06 +07
```

Is there some obscure option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setopt aliases` to renable aliases as per [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-ALIASES):

> ```
> ALIASES <D>
>    Expand aliases.
> ```

The `<D>` means the option is set by default, so some configuration file must be doing a `setopt noaliases` (or `unsetopt aliases` or `set +o aliases` or `set -o noaliases` or `options[aliases]=off`...).

(Note `noaliases` and `no_aLIAses` are the same to `zsh`).